# Oracle, store the result of a parametrized function to avoid recalculation

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to store the result of a function on a map in a select, to avoid the recalculation?

I have a query, simplified is

```
SELECT MyFunction(PARAM1 => table.col1, PARAM2 => table.col2) result 
FROM table 
GROUP BY MyFunction(PARAM1 => table.col1, PARAM2 => table.col2);
```

but there are a lot of col1/col2 duplicates.

Is there a way to save the result of the tuple "table.col1/table.col2" to recall faster the result of the function in the group by?

I tried using subqueries as

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MyFunction(PARAM1 => table.col1, PARAM2 => table.col2) result FROM table)
GROUP BY result
```

or cte

```
WITH BaseResult AS (SELECT MyFunction(PARAM1 => table.col1, PARAM2 => table.col2) result FROM table)
SELECT * FROM BaseResult GROUP BY result;
```

without notable performance improvements

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, I already tried both (edited the question with the attempts)

Comment: If you declare the function as deterministic (assuming it is such) and you still see no performance improvement, then chances are good that it's already optimized as you desire. To prove otherwise, you could not declare it deterministic and then add an autonomous transaction to record how many calls are made given the known cardinality of the row source. Or you could increment a global package variable for each call, then an autonomous transaction would not be required.

Comment: Yes, it should be deterministic since it only reads from tables. I'll check if it's declared as such, thanks

Comment: Assuming it's truly called more than you desire, another option, one that I don't like a whole lot, is to use result set caching, which can make subsequent executions of a query less costly.

Comment: "it should be deterministic since it only reads from tables": that's not the definition of DETERMINISTIC: content of tables may change... PRAGMA UDF is another optimisation possible.
some doc: https://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plsql/cache/alternatives/deterministic-vs-result-cache.html
https://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plsql/cache/udf-pragma.html

Answer (score 1):

You could group first to get rid of the duplicate `col1`, `col2` values then apply the function and then group again:

```sql
WITH group_cols (col1, col2) AS (
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM   table
  GROUP BY col1, col2
),
apply_func (result) AS (
  SELECT MyFunction(
           PARAM1 => col1,
           PARAM2 => col2
         )
  FROM   group_cols
)
SELECT result
FROM   apply_func
GROUP BY result;
```

If you need to you can materialize the sub-query factoring clauses to prevent the SQL engine from merging the queries:

```sql
WITH group_cols (col1, col2) AS (
  SELECT /*+ no_merge */
         col1, col2
  FROM   table
  GROUP BY col1, col2
),
apply_func (result) AS (
  SELECT /*+ no_merge */
         MyFunction(
           PARAM1 => col1,
           PARAM2 => col2
         )
  FROM   group_cols
)
SELECT result
FROM   apply_func
GROUP BY result;
```

or, using a seemingly useless `ROWNUM` filter:

```sql
WITH group_cols (col1, col2) AS (
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  ROWNUM > 0
  GROUP BY col1, col2
),
apply_func (result) AS (
  SELECT MyFunction(
           PARAM1 => col1,
           PARAM2 => col2
         )
  FROM   group_cols
  WHERE  ROWNUM > 0
)
SELECT result
FROM   apply_func
GROUP BY result;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YbE4S-kh)

As for making the query `DETERMINISTIC`, you said:

> it should be deterministic since it only reads from tables.

That is **NOT** deterministic as the query can get two different results between now and 5 minutes time if the table is modified in that time period. A `DETERMINISTIC` function will always return the same value for the same input and will (probably) not read from tables.

Comment: About the deterministic, what I meant was that i expect that to be so, that no one would update the tables while I'm executing the query and therefore i want the result to be the same.

Comment: When would the "deterministic" cache be invalidated, though?

Comment: @Mewster You should not make a function `DETERMINISTIC` if it is not actually deterministic. In your case, reading from a table is probably sufficient to ensure that the function is non-deterministic.